# Async function immediately returns undefined yet output variable returns a value immediately before the return statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, imagemagick-convert

I am writing a function that downloads and converts a pdf into individual jpg files by page. I am using the imagemagick library to do the conversion. I am having trouble with my `processPDF()` function as it immediately returns undefined. I put a `console.log` statement immediately before the function returns and it returns the exact value I expect yet that value doesn't seem to be getting outside of the function for some reason.

```js
import im from 'imagemagick'
import { promises as fs } from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import _ from 'lodash'
import axios from 'axios'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'

async function processPDF(pdfPath) {
    let basename = path.basename(pdfPath, '.pdf')
    let outputPath = "./img/" + basename + ".jpg";

    console.log(`Converting ${pdfPath}`)

    // Take PDF file and generate individual JPG files
    await im.convert(["-density", 300, pdfPath, outputPath],async (err) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            throw `Couldn't Process ${pdfPath}`
        }
        else {

            // Get every file in Temporary Image Directory
            let files = await fs.readdir(`./img/`)

            // Append directory into filenames
            files = files.map(file => {
                return "./img/" + file
            })

            // We only want the files that match the source pdf's name
            files = files.filter((file) => {
                return file.includes(basename)
            })

            console.log(`Getting ${basename} Buffer Data`)

            // For each file, read and return the buffer data along with the path
           let images = await Promise.all(files.map(async file => {
                const contents = await fs.readFile(file)
                return { path: file, buffer: contents }
            }))

            // Since we read the files asynchonously, Reorder the files
            images = _.orderBy(images, (image) => {
                let regex = /\d*.jpg/
                let res = image.path.match(regex)[0]
                res = path.basename(res, '.jpg')
                return res
            })
            
            let output = { pdf: pdfPath, images }

            // Returns a value
            console.log(output)

            // Returns undefined???
            return output
        }
    })
}

export async function downloadAndProcessPDF(url) {

    // Fetch PDF from server
    let { data } = await axios.get(url, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/pdf'
        }
    }).catch(e=>{
        console.log(e);
        throw `Can't retrieve ${url}`
    })

    // Generate a Unique ID for the pdf since this is called asynchronously, this will be called many times simultaneously
    let id = "./pdf/" + uuid() + ".pdf"
    await fs.writeFile(id, data);

    // tell processPDF to process the pdf in the ./pdf directory with the given filename
    let pdfData = await processPDF(id);

    // Returns undefined???
    console.log(pdfData)
    return pdfData
}
```

If I had to take a wild guess I'd think that im.convert is the function that is giving me trouble. Throughout my source code i'm using promises to handle asynchronous tasks yet `im.convert()` uses a callback function. I'm not super familiar with how concurrency works between promises and callback functions so I think that's what's probably the issue.

Comment: `im.convert` doesn't return a `Promise`; you can't await it. Either add a second callback to return your result or wrap the whole thing in a `Promise`.

Comment: And, your `async` function does not return `undefined`.,  It returns a promise that isn't connected to all to your asynchronous operation because of what teppic points out.

Comment: The intended purpose of this function is to handle multiple files simultaneously, not a single file a bunch of times. As per teppic's suggestion wrapping `im.convert` in a promise did the trick